# iOS confusing logs : Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

Tags: ios, constraints

Xcode print these logs in console, but I didn't find any conflict among these constraints. Can anybody find out where the problem is ? Thanks in advance.

```
2018-03-23 19:43:30.120496+0800 XXXX[2666:305888] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d4497020 UIImageView:0x11dc36600.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x11dc362a0.top + 15>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d4497340 UIImageView:0x11dc36830.top == UIImageView:0x11dc36600.top>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d4497430 UIImageView:0x11dc36830.height == 50>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d44974d0 UIImageView:0x11dc36830.bottom <= UITableViewCellContentView:0x11dc362a0.bottom - 15>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d4497c50 UITableViewCellContentView:0x11dc362a0.height == 80>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d4497430 UIImageView:0x11dc36830.height == 50>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

I add a [demo in github](https://github.com/kudocc/AutolayoutDemo). The table view cell is autoresizing, so I add a constraint to calculate UITableViewCell's height.

Comment: Please go to this site and paste these constraints log https://www.wtfautolayout.com/

Comment: interesting, simple math tells me that there should be no conflict there.. just for the fun of it, try to change the constant in bottom constraint from -15 to -14

Comment: can you provide a reproducible minimal example showing the issues?

Comment: Do you have only 2 elements in cell ?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ I added a demo.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Added a demo in question.

Answer (score 2):

On `UIImageView` instance `UIImageView:0x11dc36830`you are trying to specify a **top**, **bottom** and **height** *simultaneously*.

This doesn't make sense, so Xcode is breaking the height constraint.

Imagine if I said your head was at 6ft high, your feet at 0ft, but your height was 5ft, what would you look like? :)

Comment: if you read the log carefully, those constraints are not conflicting - the cell height is supposed to be 80, which is 15+50+15 - 50 points of imageView height, 15 points offset from top and 15 points offset from bottom.. am I missing something?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ I disagree.

Comment: well, you have the right to disagree, but can you please provide some math to explain why you disagree?

Comment: In a implied, triangulated system you cannot specify all three vectors.

Comment: can you elaborate for those less skilled? as I see it, OP is saying through constraints that `imageTop = cellTop + 15`, `imageBottom = imageTop + 50`, `imageBottom >= cellBottom - 15`, which holds when `cellHeight >= 80`. So adding a constraint that sets `cellHeight = 80` does not seem to be conflicting, just narrowing the possible solutions to the set of these equations to a single one. In you example, it is like saying that my head is at 5ft high, my feet at 0ft, and my height was 5ft. why would not that be possible?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ a quirk of autolayout. It's quite unforgiving. The precision on calculations can be fuzzy and applied in iterations. Ergo, at some point during calculation on the autolayout engine, these calculations conflict, maybe even only by 0.0000X. Long story short, autolayout should be used to specify the minimum number of vectors required to infer layout.

Comment: The TableView is autoresizing, so I have to set a constraint to its height, if I remove the `<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d4497430 UIImageView:0x11dc36830.height == 50>` constraint, UIKit can't figure out the height of TableViewCell. I have added a demo in my question, it may help to demonstrate.

Comment: @KudoCC Then change your priority of height constraint or give bottom constraint with >= relation you should check my answer also

Answer (score -1):

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d4497340 UIImageView:0x11dc36830.top == UIImageView:0x11dc36600.top>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d4497430 UIImageView:0x11dc36830.height == 50>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1d44974d0 UIImageView:0x11dc36830.bottom <= UITableViewCellContentView:0x11dc362a0.bottom - 15>"
```

you have added height plus top & bottom that means you want the size of imageview resize with tableviewcell & at the same time you want the height to be 50.
To solve this either delete height = 50 constraint or make height >= 50